# Why the memory space malloc in the function cannot be accessed outside the function using c

Tags: c

I am trying to solve the Leetcode question "Generate Parentheses" using C, and I encounter question when allocating the memory.

And here's the code.

```
void generator(int n, char*** arr, char* cur, int l, int r, int *returnsize){
    /*
    n : numbers of set of parentheses
    arr : the array that store the result of the outputs(answers)
    cur : the current string
    l : current left parenthese numbers
    r : current right parenthese numbers
    */
    if(l + r == n * 2){
        (arr)[(*returnsize)] = malloc(sizeof(char *));
        *(arr)[(*returnsize)++] = cur;
        printf("%s\n", cur);
        printf("%d\n", *returnsize);
        return;
    }
    
    if(l < n){
        char *str1 = malloc(l + r + 1);
        strcpy(str1, cur);
        strcat(str1, "(");
        //printf("%s ", cur);
        generator(n, arr, str1, l+1, r, returnsize);
    }
    
    if(l > r && r < n){
        char *str2 = malloc(l + r + 1);
        strcpy(str2, cur);
        strcat(str2, ")");
        //printf("%s ", cur);
        generator(n, arr, str2, l, r+1, returnsize);
    }
}

char** generateParenthesis(int n, int* returnSize){

    char** generatedlist;
    char* str = malloc(sizeof(char) * n);
    generator(n, &generatedlist, str, 0, 0, returnSize);

    for(int i = 0; i < *returnSize; i++){
        printf("%s\n", generatedlist[i]); //the code dies here
    }

    return generatedlist;
    
}
```

The results in the generator recursive function perform well.

But when I tried to print the result in the generateParenthesis function, it will cause segmentation fault when printing the generatedlist[1]. I'm wondering whether the way I malloc memory to the pointer is correct or not?

Comment: The size passed to your first `malloc` is almost certainly wrong.  Run your code under valgrind or compile with the address sanitizer enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't show us how you call `generateParenthesis` but I assume that it's like:

```
int n = SOME_VALUE;
int returnSize = 0;  // Important !! Initialized to zero
char** list = generateParenthesis(n, &returnSize);
```

Then during your recursion, you'll sooner or later reach this line:

```
(arr)[(*returnsize)] = malloc(sizeof(char *));
```

with `*returnsize` being `0` (zero). So you really do

```
arr[0] = malloc(sizeof(char *));
```

which is fine as it actually assigns a value to `generatedlist` in the caller.

However, you then increment `*returnsize` so the next time you reach:

```
(arr)[(*returnsize)] = malloc(sizeof(char *));
```

you really do

```
arr[1] = malloc(sizeof(char *));
```

and that is real bad. The memory at that address (`arr[1]`) doesn't "belong" to an array of "pointer-to-char". It is only `arr[0]` that access a legal location (i.e. `generatedlist`) while `arr[1]` access the memory **after** `generatedlist`. In other words - illegal memory access.

As far as I can tell, you want `generatedlist` to point to **an array of char-pointers** and further you want each of those char-pointers to point to an array of chars where you want to store a string. Something like:

[image]

To do that you need to use `realloc`. That is something like:

```
++NUM_STR;                                     // increase number of strings
*arr = realloc(*arr, NUM_STR);                 // extend the pointer array
assert(*arr != NULL);                          // just exit if realloc fails
(*arr)[NUM_STR-1] = malloc(SIZE_OF_STRING);    // allocate char for a new string
```

and make sure to initialize `generatedlist` like

```
char** generatedlist = NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. but I just encounter problem when reallocing the `*arr`, after `realloc` , it seems that the memory allocated to the `*arr` doesn't increase. Under the debug mode of vscode, I found out that I could only access `**arr` and `*(arr)[1]` but could not access further even if I have realloc the enough memory for the pointer.

Comment: It seems like this [picture](https://imgur.com/d2dTNI9)

Comment: @ChouChen See https://ideone.com/q4f5Ae It shows how you allocate the memory. If that doesn't help you can do this: Edit your question and write "Based on answers I changed my code to the code below but it still fails. <describe fail>." **Add the new code below current code. Do not edit or delete current code**